# How to improve performance of my spark-sql-joins

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have two data sources(both csv files) , one is an incoming data source (2.2 million records) with and the master data source (35 million records) . My job is to verify how many of the records in the incoming datasource match the master datasource and output them . The key here is that the records are noisy and need fuzzy string matching instead of exact matching. My join works well on small data, but when I have to do the same for big data it is taking forever.

FYI .. With this code , it took me about 1 hr 40 mins to perform a join on incoming data(1m records) vs master data(3 million records), on a 8 core machine.

For example. 
Master datasource has one of the 35 million records as show below

"Markets, Inc.",1 Bank Plz,,Chicago,IL,60670-0001,IL

Incoming data has one of the records

"Markets Inc",1 Bank Pl,,Chicago,IL,60670-0001,IL

below is my code

```
def myFunc: (String => String) = {
      s =>
        if (s.length > 5) {
          s.substring(0, 5)
        } else s
    }
val myUDF = udf(myFunc)
var sourcedata = spark.sqlContext.read.option("header", "true").option("delimiter", "|")
  .csv("./src/main/resources/company_address_sample3000000.txt").na.fill("")
  .select(col("COMPANY_NAME").alias("NAME1"), concat(col("STREET_ADDR_1"),
    col("STREET_ADDR_2")).alias("ADDRESS1"), col("CITY").alias("CITY1"), col("STATE").alias("STATE1"),
    myUDF(col("ZIP")).alias("ZIP1"))
  .withColumn("Beginswith1", col("NAME1").substr(0, 1)).distinct()
  .repartition(col("Beginswith1"), col("NAME1"), col("ADDRESS1"), col("CITY1"), col("STATE1"), col("ZIP1"))
var incomingData = spark.sqlContext.read.option("header", "true").option("delimiter", "|")
  .csv("./src/main/resources/common_format_sample1000000.txt")
  .select("NAME", "ADDRESS", "CITY", "STATE", "ZIP")
  .withColumn("Beginswith", col("NAME").substr(0, 1)).distinct()
  .repartition(col("Beginswith"), col("NAME"), col("ADDRESS"), col("CITY"), col("STATE"), col("ZIP"))

def calculate_similarity(str: String, str1: String): Double = {
  val dist = new JaroWinkler()
  Try {
    dist.similarity(str, str1)
  } getOrElse (0.0)
}

def myFilterFunction(
                      nameInp: String, nameRef: String,
                      addInp: String, addRef: String,
                      cityInp: String, cityRef: String,
                      stateInp: String, stateRef: String,
                      zipInp: String, zipRef: String
                    ) = {
  stateInp == stateRef && cityInp == cityRef && calculate_similarity(nameInp, nameRef) > 0.8 && calculate_similarity(addInp, addRef) > 0.8
}

val udf1 = org.apache.spark.sql.functions.udf(myFilterFunction _)
val filter: Column = udf1(
  incomingData("NAME"), sourcedata("NAME1"),
  incomingData("ADDRESS"), sourcedata("ADDRESS1"),
  incomingData("CITY"), sourcedata("CITY1"),
  incomingData("STATE"), sourcedata("STATE1"),
  incomingData("ZIP"), sourcedata("ZIP1")
)

incomingData.join(sourcedata, incomingData("Beginswith") === sourcedata("Beginswith1") && filter, "left_semi")
  .write.csv("./src/main/resources/hihello3-0.8-1m3m.csv")
```

Comment: I would first make sure the database is optimized. (indexes, partitioned, etc)
I then write a python script, that checks the raw value from the noisy data source against the db, if match. move on. else, start the fuzzy logic nightmare. Identify columns that must match 100% then move backwards from there. Update the db with a 'reviewed' column to know that you have evaluated it, and perhaps a timestamp.

Comment: thanks for the advise, but i changed my question description above.

Answer (score 0):

Rearranging the join filter sequence,has reduced the time significantly from 1hr50 mins to 90 secs .
While this is not a solution from sql optimization perspective, it served my current purpose, given my data.
I would still love to see if someone comes up with a solution, from sql optimization perspective.

```
var sourcedata = spark.sqlContext.read.option("header", "true").option("delimiter", "|")
      .csv("./src/main/resources/company_address.txt").na.fill("")
      .select(col("COMPANY_NAME").alias("NAME1"), concat(col("STREET_ADDR_1"),
        col("STREET_ADDR_2")).alias("ADDRESS1"), col("CITY").alias("CITY1"), col("STATE").alias("STATE1"),
        col("ZIP").alias("ZIP1"))
      .withColumn("Beginswith1", col("NAME1").substr(0, 1))
      .repartition(col("Beginswith1"), col("NAME1"), col("ADDRESS1"), col("CITY1"), col("STATE1"), col("ZIP1"))

var incomingData_Select = spark.sqlContext.read.option("header", "true").option("delimiter", "|")
  .csv("./src/main/resources/common_format.txt")
  .select("NAME", "ADDRESS", "CITY", "STATE", "ZIP")
  .withColumn("Beginswith", col("NAME").substr(0, 1)).distinct()
  .repartition(col("Beginswith"), col("NAME"), col("ADDRESS"), col("CITY"), col("STATE"), col("ZIP"))

def calculate_similarity(str: String, str1: String, str2: String, str3: String): Boolean = {
  val dist = new JaroWinkler()
  Try {
    dist.similarity(str, str1) > 0.8 && dist.similarity(str2, str3) > 0.8
  } getOrElse (false)
}

def myFilterFunction(
                      nameInp: String, nameRef: String,
                      addInp: String, addRef: String
                    ) = {
  calculate_similarity(nameInp, nameRef, addInp, addRef)
}

val sim_udf = org.apache.spark.sql.functions.udf(myFilterFunction _)

val filter: Column = sim_udf(
  incomingData_Select("NAME"), sourcedata("NAME1"),
  incomingData_Select("ADDRESS"), sourcedata("ADDRESS1")
)

val matching_companies = incomingData_Select
  .join(sourcedata, incomingData_Select("STATE") === sourcedata("STATE1") && incomingData_Select("CITY") === sourcedata("CITY1") && incomingData_Select("Beginswith") === sourcedata("Beginswith1") && filter, "left_semi")
```